# R: конвертировать xts ряд в нестандартные периоды

Tags: r

в R имею объект D1 типа xts, все строки с минутным интервалом, вида:

```
                    Open  High   Low Close Volume
2016-01-04 10:00:00 74851 74851 74116 74150  42611
2016-01-04 10:01:00 74151 74264 74085 74249  30638
.....
2016-02-15 23:38:00 77838 77843 77563 77600  64776
```

Мне нужно преобразовать его в часовые интервалы, но с разбиением равным концу строки. К сожалению, функция xts::to.period все равно конвертирует только на границе целого часа:

```
tail( to.period(D1, period = "minutes", k=60, indexAt = "lastof"), 3 )

2016-02-15 21:59:00 78270 78273 77841 77986 116996
2016-02-15 22:59:00 77984 78075 77743 77841  83949
2016-02-15 23:38:00 77838 77843 77563 77600  64776
```

a нужно так:

```
2016-01-04 10:38:00 xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
2016-01-04 11:38:00 xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
.....
2016-02-15 23:38:00 xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

...

Сейчас делаю в цикле, но хочется получить решение в векторном виде

Comment: Думаю если бы вы показали `dput` данных и  то как вы делаете циклом могло бы упростить поиск решения в векторном виде.

Comment: Посмотрите свежий пакет [tibbletime](https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime). Удивительно могучая штука для подобных задач

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Отвечу сам себе.

```
offset<-38 # на какую минуту делать отсечку
zpoint<-align.time( index(D1)-offset*60, 3600)-3600+offset*60  # внутри каждой сгруппированной строки время присваивается по началу периода
tOpen   = as.xts(aggregate(DH$Open,  zpoint, head, 1 ))
tHigh   = as.xts(aggregate(DH$High,  zpoint, max  ))
tLow    = as.xts(aggregate(DH$Low,   zpoint, min  ))    
tClose  = as.xts(aggregate(DH$Close, zpoint, tail, 1 ))
tVolume = as.xts(aggregate(DH$Volume,zpoint, sum  ))    
D2<-as.xts ( data.frame(Open=tOpen, High=tHigh, Low=tLow, Close=tClose, Volume=tVolume ) ) # что и требовалось
```